# How to Plot a Horizontal Histogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I looked and couldn't find an answer for this question, so here goes.

I have some data (a 1 X 1000 vector called data) that I would like to plot the histogram information for.  If I use the `histogram(data)` command then I get a nice enough histogram plot where the x-axis is the divided evenly into ten buckets (midpoint values of the ten equal intervals between the max and min values of the data) and the y-axis records how many occurances occured for each bucket.

What I really want is the same plot, just with the y-axis representing the bucket intervals, and the x-axis representing the count for each bucket...

That way I can stick it into a subplot next to some other information, and everything will be easier to understand (and look super cool).  What's an easy way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the [`barh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/barh.html) function. Here's an example:

```
testData = randn(10000,1); %# test data
[counts,bins] = hist(testData); %# get counts and bin locations
barh(bins,counts)
```

[image]

#### Flipping the bar chart

Here's an example showing how to flip the chart along a vertical axis.

```
h=barh(bins,counts); %# include previous two lines from above
set(get(h,'Parent'),'xdir','r')
```

[image]

Comment: The call should be `barh(f,z)`, maybe you should use better variable names :) Also if you want to get the same spacing behavior as the HIST plot, add a third argument: `barh(bins,counts,'hist')`

Comment: @Amro:  Cool!  Thanks for the correction, I was trying it out and getting the plot of a barren christmas tree...  but now it works.

Comment: @amro Lol, thanks! That totally was due to silly variable names. I wrote the answer without MATLAB and fired it up and included the plot within the 5 minute window. While I fixed it in my terminal, I forgot to do it here

Comment: @Jimmy Consider it an early Christmas greetings from me :D

Comment: Great, now it looks perfect.  I notice that `barh` takes y values first, and x values second.  I also notice there is no function `ploth` -- so I guess for a swapped plot, you can just swap the vectors, which leads me to this question:  "Can you have the bars start from the right and grow out to the left?"  Basically, the exact same plot, just reflected on a vertical axis?

Comment: @Jimmy I think they kept `barh` that way so that it's consistent with the syntax of `bar`. As for your second question, try `set(gca,'xdir','r')`. This should flip the increasing values in the `x-axis` from right to left. I can't test it now, as I don't have access to MATLAB at the moment, but I'm pretty sure it should work. It'd be great if you could confirm if this helps.

Comment: @Yoda:  Yeah, so I tried the various combinations of `set(gca,['xdir'|'ydir'],['r'|'reverse'|'normal'])` and couldn't get the bar chart to budge an inch...  which is a bummer, because now I really want a stalactite bar chart that grows down from the ceiling!  Should I start another question and close this one?  Thanks again, and happy new year!

Comment: @Jimmy No, I'm very certain this should work. Just give me a few minutes and I'll post an example when I get access to MATLAB. One problem could've been because the right plot was not selected and `gca` captures the wrong one. This can be offset by using axes handles. Also, please do not migrate this to chat. I hate it.

Comment: @Yoda, yeah, I tried to use your simple example and just stick that `set` statement right before the call to `barh`... I will check back here for your example in a little bit, gotta go teach right now, thanks again!

Comment: @Jimmy Ah, that's the mistake. The call to `set` should've been _after_ the call to `barh`. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 5):

since the HISTOGRAM function was introduced (R2014b),  you can make a horizontal histogram by setting 'orientation' to 'horizontal'

example:

```
histogram(data,'orientation','horizontal')
```

Comment: The `histogram` function also does not reorder the bars according to names (unlike `bar` or `hbar` functions).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the regular histogram function *hist* and then change the point of view by typing

```
>> view(90, -90)
```