# Horizontal(sideways) histogram - gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram

My question is is there a way to make a [horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774402/how-to-plot-a-horizontal-histogram-in-matlab) histogram in gnuplot?
The following is a made up dataset for a histogram plot:

```
sample  M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   Total
A   39.17   8.33    11.07   8.57    22.20   22.93   1.47    1.13    114.87
B   61.68   15.53   16.23   15.55   35.68   36.35   2.32    2.23    185.58
C   30.20   7.35    7.55    7.48    16.90   17.50   1.18    1.10    89.25
D   12.57   5.18    4.98    5.77    9.88    8.18    0.67    0.83    48.07
E   36.80   9.00    11.07   9.43    21.43   22.63   0.93    1.03    112.33
F   62.05   15.57   15.95   15.70   35.68   36.63   2.27    2.47    186.32
G   30.23   7.33    7.55    7.48    17.10   17.68   1.10    1.25    89.70
H   12.97   4.87    5.22    5.18    10.37   7.90    0.98    0.70    48.18
I   17.67   12.80   9.40    5.67    32.47   18.53   1.13    0.63    98.30
J   72.30   13.70   17.43   15.43   30.62   38.43   2.25    2.43    192.60
K   25.70   7.58    12.45   4.60    19.30   18.88   1.10    0.80    90.40
L   16.15   3.80    3.53    10.43   7.27    8.80    0.88    1.10    51.97
```

I adapted the code from [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/histograms.5.gnu) to plot a histogram:

```
    set terminal png font "Times-Roman,9" 
    set output 'sample.png'
    set border 3 front linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
    set boxwidth 0.85 absolute
    set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
    set grid nopolar
    set grid noxtics nomxtics ytics nomytics noztics nomztics \
    nox2tics nomx2tics noy2tics nomy2tics nocbtics nomcbtics
    set grid layerdefault   linetype 0 linewidth 1.000,  linetype 0 linewidth 1.000
    set key outside right top vertical Left reverse noenhanced autotitles columnhead nobox
    set key invert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 
    set style histogram rowstacked title  offset character 0, 0, 0
    set datafile missing '-'
    set style data histograms
    #set style histogram gap 1
    set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
    set xtics  norangelimit font ",8"
    set xtics   ()
    #set noytics
    set ylabel "% of total" 
    set yrange [ 0 : 100 ] #noreverse nowriteback
    plot 'sample.txt' using (100.*$2/$10):xtic(1) t column(2), for [i=3:9] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(10)) title column(i)
```

This gives me:

[image: Histogram]

Is there a way in gnuplot to make it go sideways?

Comment: AFAIK, gnuplot doesn't currently do horizontal histograms.

Comment: Right, gnuplot doesn't support horizontal histograms out of the box, but it would be possible with some workaround: 1. Using the `boxxyerrorbars` plotting style, see [Gnuplot interchanging Axes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898979/2604213), 2. Using the `y2`-axis, rotating the labels and rotating the whole plot at the end, see [Anyone have a way to plot a bean plot in gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19266711/2604213). The latter wouldn't work with the automatic key.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but still kind of unanswered.
As @Christoph suggested, the plotting style `boxxyerror` is the way to go for a workaround.
However, so far I haven't seen example code, e.g. on the gnuplot demo page.
And as far as I know, gnuplot 5.2.8 and probably 5.4 still don't have a plotting style horizontal stacked histogram (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Actually, the column "Total" is not necessary, because gnuplot can do the total sum automatically. I guess the function `sum` is available since 4.6.0. With the "Total" column, it might work with some adaption even with earlier versions (however, no `stats` at that times).

*Update:*

- *changed* `boxxyerror` *from 6 column to shorter 4 column syntax. Check* `help boxxyerror`.
- *automatic extraction of number of data columns. gnuplot>=5.x has* `STATS_columns` *for this.*

**Data:** `SO19800832.dat`

```
sample M       N       O       P       Q       R       S      T      Total
A      39.17    8.33   11.07    8.57   22.20   22.93   1.47   1.13   114.87
B      61.68   15.53   16.23   15.55   35.68   36.35   2.32   2.23   185.58
C      30.20    7.35    7.55    7.48   16.90   17.50   1.18   1.10    89.25
D      12.57    5.18    4.98    5.77    9.88    8.18   0.67   0.83    48.07
E      36.80    9.00   11.07    9.43   21.43   22.63   0.93   1.03   112.33
F      62.05   15.57   15.95   15.70   35.68   36.63   2.27   2.47   186.32
G      30.23    7.33    7.55    7.48   17.10   17.68   1.10   1.25    89.70
H      12.97    4.87    5.22    5.18   10.37    7.90   0.98   0.70    48.18
I      17.67   12.80    9.40    5.67   32.47   18.53   1.13   0.63    98.30
J      72.30   13.70   17.43   15.43   30.62   38.43   2.25   2.43   192.60
K      25.70    7.58   12.45    4.60   19.30   18.88   1.10   0.80    90.40
L      16.15    3.80    3.53   10.43    7.27    8.80   0.88   1.10    51.97
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### horizontal stacked histogram
reset

FILE = "SO19800832.dat"

set xlabel "% of total"
set xrange [0:103]
set yrange [:] reverse
set offsets 0,0,0.5,0.5
set style fill solid 1.0
set key out

# automatic extraction of number of columns
set datafile separator "@"     # some character which does not appear in the file
stats FILE u (ColCount=words(strcol(1))-2) nooutput
set datafile separator whitespace

myBoxwidth = 0.8

plot for [col=2:ColCount+1] FILE u (total=sum [i=2:ColCount+1] column(i), \
     x0=column(col),((sum [i=2:col-1] column(i))+x0/2.)/total*100):0: \
     (x0/2./total*100):(myBoxwidth/2.):ytic(1) w boxxy ti columnhead(col)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]